# Printing the result of the script(running in background) on the terminal

Tags: perl, tcl

I am writing a perl script which runs another tcl script from it. The terminal doesn't print anything and waits for the tcl script to complete.

`` `chmod +x runme.tcl`; `./runme.tcl 2>&1`; ``

Can anyone please help me on how to print the results of the tcl script on the terminal instead of just waiting for it to get completed?

Thank you

Comment: Backticks capture the output of the command, you probably want `system`

Comment: @AKHolland Thanks you so much. It worked with "system"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
system('chmod +x runme.tcl');
system('/runme.tcl 2>&1');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run `tcl` scripts directly from `perl` using the [`Tcl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tcl) module without having to mess around with `qx` or `system`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tcl;

Tcl->new->EvalFile("runme.tcl");
```

It'll share the same standard output as the perl script.

If you're using a new enough version of `Tcl`, you can easily create a [safe interpreter](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/interp.htm#M44) to evaluate the script in case it tries to do anything nasty:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tcl v1.05;

my $interp = Tcl->new;
my $safeinterp = $interp->CreateSlave("safeinterp", 1);
$interp->Eval('interp share {} stdout safeinterp');
$interp->Eval('interp share {} stderr safeinterp');
$safeinterp->EvalFile("runme.tcl");
```

Comment: (This is probably overkill for OP unless he wants to sandbox the tcl script, but I was inspired to follow through on my comment on mob's answer and see if that idea was possible)

Answer (score 1):

Backticks capture the output of an external command. You can write that output with a `print` command in front of the backticks.

```
`chmod +x runme.tcl`; print `./runme.tcl 2>&1`;
```

Comment: I'd use `system` for the chmod. Or better yet, do it in Perl directly instead of invoking a shell.

Comment: Shoot, there's probably a module to control a tcl interpreter from perl that can be used to run the script.